# Get amount of records with specific value, but only once per unique field

Tags: mysql, database, recordset

I'm not looking for a complete answer, but maybe some pointers as to what kind of mysql commands I should look at to figure this out.

I have a series of sensors (30+) connected to my network. At different intervals I request their status and each of the devices replies with n-amount of booleans, where n can be anything from zero to 120 (so the response can be an empty object, a list of 120 booleans, or any amount in between).

Per received boolean I create a new record, together with the device's mac address and a timestamp. For example ([see also this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0995c1/1)):

```
+----+-------------------+---------------------+--------+    
| id | device_address    | timestamp           | status |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+--------+    
|  1 | f2:49:d2:17:5d:8d | 2018-09-22 15:54:51 |      0 |
|  2 | fd:30:ec:08:67:9a | 2018-09-22 15:54:56 |      0 |
|  3 | f8:8d:d9:64:a4:7c | 2018-09-22 15:54:58 |      1 |
|  4 | f2:49:d2:17:5d:8d | 2018-09-22 15:55:51 |      0 |
|  5 | f2:49:d2:17:5d:8d | 2018-09-22 15:55:52 |      0 |
|  6 | fd:30:ec:08:67:9a | 2018-09-22 15:55:56 |      1 |
|  7 | f8:8d:d9:64:a4:7c | 2018-09-22 15:55:58 |      1 |
|  8 | f2:49:d2:17:5d:8d | 2018-09-22 15:56:52 |      0 |
|  9 | f2:49:d2:17:5d:8d | 2018-09-22 15:57:52 |      1 |
| 10 | f2:49:d2:17:5d:8d | 2018-09-22 15:58:52 |      1 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

Or, with the mac address replaced for better readability:

```
+----+-------------------+---------------------+--------+    
| id | device_address    | timestamp           | status |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+--------+    
|  1 | A                 | 2018-09-22 15:54:51 |      0 |
|  2 | BB                | 2018-09-22 15:54:56 |      0 |
|  3 | CCC               | 2018-09-22 15:54:58 |      1 |
|  4 | A                 | 2018-09-22 15:55:51 |      0 |
|  5 | A                 | 2018-09-22 15:55:52 |      0 |
|  6 | BB                | 2018-09-22 15:55:56 |      1 |
|  7 | CCC               | 2018-09-22 15:55:58 |      1 |
|  8 | A                 | 2018-09-22 15:56:52 |      0 |
|  9 | A                 | 2018-09-22 15:57:52 |      1 |
| 10 | A                 | 2018-09-22 15:58:52 |      1 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

In the end I want to be able to graph these values, grouped in intervals. For example, when I graph the last 2 hours worth of data, I want to use 5 minute intervals. Per interval I want to know how many (unique) devices had a status of 1 at least once in that period, and how many only had zeroes. Devices that don't appear within the timeblock at all (because they didn't return a boolean) are not relevant to that timeblock

The above records would fall within two of such 5 minute timeblocks:

- 15:50:00 to 15:54:59 - ids 1 2 3
- 15:55:00 to 15:59:59 - ids 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

The kind of response I'd like is something like this:

```
+---------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+    
| timeblock start     | dev w/ at least one status of 1 | dev w/ only status of 0 |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+    
| 2018-09-22 15:50:00 |                               1 |                       2 |
| 2018-09-22 15:55:00 |                               2 |                       1 |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

The final result does not have to be like this exactly, other results that can help me deduce these numbers would also work. The same is true for the timestamp field; this `2018-09-22 15:50:00` format would be great but other formats can also allow me to deduct what the timeblock was.

Doing something like this gets me the different timeblocks and the amount of unique devices within each timeblock, but it counts the total amount of 1s and 0s instead of combining the results of each unique device.

```
SELECT timestamp, 
SUM(status) as ones, COUNT(status)-SUM(status) as zeroes, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(device_address)) as unique_devices 
FROM records 
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 300 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

result:

```
+----------------------+------+--------+----------------+
| timestamp            | ones | zeroes | unique devices |
+----------------------+------+--------+----------------+
| 2018-09-22T15:54:51Z |    1 |      2 |              3 |
| 2018-09-22T15:57:52Z |    4 |      3 |              3 |
+----------------------+------+--------+----------------+
```

Comment: The mentioned dataset was a simplified version, the result set was from my actual database. I've changed them so they match.

Comment: I'm still struggling to see why '16:49:59' would be a valid result

Comment: I'm not sure why, but before I got those values when grouping into blocks with 5 minute intervals. Don't seem to get them with my current code. One of those things were you've tried so many options you're not sure what code did what... But my main problem is with getting the right amount of statuses.

Comment: I think your main probelem is asking a coherent question! See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sorry, I think you're right and I fell into the 'but my dataset is easy' trap. Add some 'not completely sure how this should work' and the confusion is complete.
I'll rewrite the question and add a MCVE.

Comment: I believe that you have an error in the expected error. There are three devices with status one in the second interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT timestamp, 
       count(distinct case when status = 1 then device_address end) as ones, 
       count(distinct case when status = 0 then device_address end) as zeros, 
FROM records 
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 300 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0995c1/8)

Comment: Makes total sense written like that. So basically you add the devices addresses to one of two lists, depending on the status, and then count the amount of unique addresses in both lists? That's great, thank you

Comment: @jasper exactly, the whole result will be computed by one sequential scan. You are welcome :)